# Points displacement - capture new coordinates?

Tags: qgis

I have a vector layer of points - say, rooms for rent in a city. Definitely, several rooms are up for rent in one building, so these would share the same coordinates. I need all my rooms to have unique coordinates (say, rooms 1 and 2 in the same building just a few meters apart), so I try points displacement.

Points displacement seems to work visually, but how will I get the new coordinates of the displaced points? "Add geometry column" still exports the original coordinates.

/Edit: I just learned the term, so: what I want is to get the coordinates of the digitized points. I end up with a ring of points (rooms) around the original point (building), but the coordinates of those rooms still end up the same as the original building.

Answer (score 3):

There are two point displacement options, one is the *renderer* [Point Displacement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHlDq.png), found in the Styles tab, and the other is the *geoprocessing* [Points Displacement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0Z9x.png), found in the Processing Toolbox.

First one will be just a visual change, the second one will be permanent (but not on the original data, you save your changes to a new layer). Use the second one, and you should have your new coordinates.

Comment: The Points Displacement in the Processing Toolbox is what I use; then what? The new layer doesn't have new coordinates in the attributes table, and adding geometries still produces the same coordinates.

Comment: Is Points Displacement working in QGIS 2.18?

Comment: @JillAdona Oh, sorry for assuming otherwise. You mention attribute table, but that won't necessarily reflect the new coordinates. When you use Points Displacement, does it visually change your points? If so, what coordinates do you get for each with, say, the getWkt plugin?

Comment: @Shimbamangu Yes, it still works.

Comment: @RobertoRibeiro Yes, it does visually change my points - when I hover over the new points I see new coordinates at the bottom right of my screen. Then I use Export/Add geometry column, but the coordinates I get for each observation are still the same as the original building. I'll check the plugin you mentioned!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem too – and found that exporting with AS_XY as GEOMETRY on layer options exported the displaced points correctly.

[image: screenshot showing AS_XY in Geometry layer options settings]